# How to build a feature branch (instead of master)?

Tags: git, branch, autotools

I am working on a project which uses GNU Autotools for it to be built.
I created a new feature branch - MyFeature from the master branch.

```
git checkout -b MyFeature
```

Now, I made some changes in the source code in the MyFeature branch.(How to check if these changes are working - build the new source code?)
When I build the code using

```
./bootstrap
./configure
make
```

Which code will be built? The unchanged code on the master branch? or the changed code on the MyFeature branch?

If the second one, then will this replace the previously built package(from the master branch) on my system?

Comment: What makes you think master would be built instead of your new code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system will build the packages using the code present on your active git branch (committed and uncommitted combined). There are various ways to find out the active git branch.

- If you are using any IDE, then somewhere at the top or bottom corner you will see the name of your active branch.
- Second, using the terminal. Open your terminal, go to the path of your working project, type `git branch -vv`, your active branch would start with `*`.

Answering your second question: "will this replace the previous built?"

It will depend upon how you are building it, which language and frameworks are you using. But generally speaking, it will try to replace the older build image from your system. Though you don't have to worry about it, the previous image can again be built by checking out your master branch and building it again there.

Comment: The current branch is also listed in the output of `git status`.  Also, I'd add that it would probably be wise to perform a clean build when one is not confident that all build results already present are attributable to the source in the active branch.  `make` *will not* replace artifacts that appear already to be up to date based on their timestamps, but changing branches makes the timestamp test unreliable.

Comment: FYI, I have written myself a tool which helps with building different git branches into different build directories and install directories to allow direct comparison of build results of different branches. See the `git amb` command from https://github.com/ndim/ndim-git-utils/ if you are interested. Basically, `git amb make` will run `make` for the current branch `foobar`, building in `_build/foobar` and installing to `_install/foobar`. Obviously, this requires the package to support out of source tree builds. `git amb` also only supports `autoreconf` for bootstrapping, but not weird scripts.